# Parameters missing from ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to add a new linked service (databricks cluster pool) to my data factory. However, I am getting the following error when trying to deploy into the higer environments:

```
##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters 'databricks_X_cluster_pool_properties_typeProperties_instancePoolId' in the parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time.
```

I am attempting to overrride `databricks_X_cluster_pool_properties_typeProperties_instancePoolId`, which apparently is missing from ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json on my publish branch. The only available properties are:

```
"databricks_X_cluster_pool_properties_typeProperties_domain": {
            "value": ""
},
"databricks_X_pool_properties_typeProperties_workspaceResourceId": {
            "value": ""
},
```

However, on my collaboration branch, I can see more properties (also the one I am interested in). Why not all of them are passed to the publish branch?

```
{
    "name": "databricks_X_cluster_pool",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureDatabricks",
        "typeProperties": {
            "domain": "test_domain",
            "authentication": "MSI",
            "workspaceResourceId": "test_workspace",
            "instancePoolId": "test_id",
            "newClusterNumOfWorker": "1",
            "newClusterVersion": "12.2.x-scala2.12",
            "newClusterInitScripts": [],
            "clusterOption": "Fixed"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share how you are building your Data Factory artifact? Is it being regenerated as part of your pipeline?